# Django Form - setting data

Tags: django, forms

I'm improving my English, be patient

My form is a ModelForm and all the necessary data is sent by the user, but I  want dynamically set the field ["viagem"] with the last object in the queryset.

How to set a field after sending the data

```
def cadastro(request):
    dono = Dono.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VendaForm(dono, request.POST)

        # Here I get the necessary data to call my qs
        colocador_id = form["colocador"].value()
        viagem = Colocador.objects.get(pk=colocador_id).viagem_set.last()
       
        # I want something like this
        form["viagem"] = viagem
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print('error')
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = VendaForm(dono)
    context = {"form": form, }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/cadastro.html', context)
```

print(form.errors) => `<ul class="errorlist"><li>viagem<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: Then you should not include this as a form field. Can you share the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should *not* add this as a Form field. You thus exclude it from the `fields` in your `ModelForm` and work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def cadastro(request):
    dono = get_object_or_404(Dono, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VendaForm(dono, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.viagem = form.cleaned_data['colocador'].viagem_set.last()
            form.save()
        else:
            print('error')
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = VendaForm(dono)
    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/cadastro.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).